# Date column is dropped after creating new column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create two new columns based on two parameters in the dataset called "community data" : Dep_Index & AU_GMP_PER_CAPITA. These give the deprivation index and the spend on gambling in communities for different areas in New Zealand. The parameters are specific to each area ( column name: AU2017_name) and a particular date on which they have been collected.

The two new columns will have: a) average of Dep_Index for a particular year (eg.2013) and specific to that area (eg.Aranui)., and b) same thing but for the AU_GMP_PER_CAPITA column.

A snapshot of the dataframe:

| AU2017_code | Date | AU_GMP_PER_CAPITA | Dep_Index | AU2017_name | TA2018_name | TALB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 500100 | 1/03/2013 | 62.73254111 | 9 | Awanui | Far North District | Far North District |
| 500202 | 1/03/2013 | 12.1231307 | 9 | Karikari Peninsula-Maungataniwha | Far North District | Far North District |
| 500203 | 1/03/2013 | 151.8410144 | 9 | Taipa Bay-Mangonui | Far North District | Far North District |
| 500204 | 1/03/2013 | 56.46501065 | 8 | Herekino | Far North District | Far North District |
| 500205 | 1/03/2013 | 0 | 9 | Ahipara | Far North District | Far North District |
| 500206 | 1/03/2013 | 0 | 10 | North Cape | Far North District | Far North District |
| 500207 | 1/03/2013 | 0 | 9 | Houhora | Far North District | Far North District |
| 500208 | 1/03/2013 | 65.58023849 | 8 | Motutangi-Kareponia | Far North District | Far North District |
| 500301 | 1/03/2013 | 197.2491364 | 10 | Kaitaia West | Far North District | Far North District |
| 500302 | 1/03/2013 | 206.8280015 | 10 | Kaitaia East | Far North District | Far North District |
| 500401 | 1/03/2013 | 0 | 10 | Kaeo | Far North District | Far North District |
| 500402 | 1/03/2013 | 0 | 9 | Mangapa-Matauri Bay | Far North District | Far North District |
| 500500 | 1/03/2013 | 22.96812827 | 10 | Kohukohu | Far North District | Far North District |
| 500600 | 1/03/2013 | 100.051763 | 10 | Rawene | Far North District | Far North District |
| 500700 | 1/03/2013 | 196.8465345 | 10 | Omapere and Opononi | Far North District | Far North District |
| 500801 | 1/03/2013 | 3.170242784 | 10 | Hokianga North | Far North District | Far North District |
| 500802 | 1/03/2013 | 18.68430235 | 10 | Hokianga South | Far North District | Far North District |
| 500900 | 1/03/2013 | 70.01595188 | 7 | Kerikeri | Far North District | Far North District |
| 501000 | 1/03/2013 | 151.5078577 | 6 | Russell | Far North District | Far North District |
| 501100 | 1/03/2013 | 187.1490424 | 8 | Paihia | Far North District | Far North District |
| 501200 | 1/03/2013 | 73.15790271 | 7 | Haruru Falls | Far North District | Far North District |
| 501300 | 1/03/2013 | 78.61958836 | 5 | Opua East | Far North District | Far North District |
| 501400 | 1/03/2013 | 390.1053264 | 10 | Kawakawa | Far North District | Far North District |
| 501500 | 1/03/2013 | 193.069158 | 10 | Moerewa | Far North District | Far North District |

I have written code but the problem is that despite setting the date as the index, once the code runs the date column is dropped in the final output.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns


#load the community data csv as a pandas dataframe
community_data = pd.read_csv('community data.csv')

# strip whitespaces from column headers
community_data.columns = [col.strip() for col in community_data.columns]

#Convert Date column from object to Datetime format
community_data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(community_data['Date'])

# Set the 'Date' column as index
community_data.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

# Filter data for the specified years
community_Data_years = community_data[community_data.index.year.isin([2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020])]

# Calculate average Dep_Index for each AU2017_name for all unique years
avg_dep_index = community_Data_years.groupby('AU2017_name')['Dep_Index'].mean().reset_index()
avg_dep_index = avg_dep_index.rename(columns={'Dep_Index':'Avg_Dep_Index'})
community_data = pd.merge(community_data, avg_dep_index, on='AU2017_name', how='left')

# Calculate average AU_GMP_PER_CAPITA for each AU2017_name for all unique years
avg_GMP_index = community_Data_years.groupby('AU2017_name')['AU_GMP_PER_CAPITA'].mean().reset_index()
avg_GMP_index = avg_GMP_index.rename(columns={'AU_GMP_PER_CAPITA':'AVG_GMP'})
community_data = pd.merge(community_data, avg_GMP_index, on='AU2017_name', how='left')

#preview output
community_data.head()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`merge` doesn't preserve index so you should not set your final index before all merge operations. However in your case, your code can be simplified with `groupby_transform` to broadcast computed `Avg_Dep_Index` and `AVG_GMP` average to all records.

Try:

```
#load the community data csv as a pandas dataframe
community_data = pd.read_csv('community data.csv')

# strip whitespaces from column headers
community_data.columns = [col.strip() for col in community_data.columns]

#Convert Date column from object to Datetime format
community_data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(community_data['Date'])

# Set the 'Date' column as index
community_data.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

# Filter data for the specified years
community_Data_years = community_data[community_data.index.year.isin(range(2013, 2021))]

# Calculate average Dep_Index for each AU2017_name for all unique years
community_data['Avg_Dep_Index'] = community_Data_years.groupby('AU2017_name', as_index=False)['Dep_Index'].transform('mean')

# Calculate average AU_GMP_PER_CAPITA for each AU2017_name for all unique years
community_data['AU_GMP'] = community_Data_years.groupby('AU2017_name')['AU_GMP_PER_CAPITA'].transform('mean')

#preview output
community_data.head()
```

Output:

```
            AU2017_code  AU_GMP_PER_CAPITA  Dep_Index                       AU2017_name         TA2018_name                TALB  Avg_Dep_Index      AU_GMP
Date                                                                                                                                                      
2013-01-03       500100          62.732541          9                            Awanui  Far North District  Far North District            9.0   62.732541
2013-01-03       500202          12.123131          9  Karikari Peninsula-Maungataniwha  Far North District  Far North District            9.0   12.123131
2013-01-03       500203         151.841014          9                Taipa Bay-Mangonui  Far North District  Far North District            9.0  151.841014
2013-01-03       500204          56.465011          8                          Herekino  Far North District  Far North District            8.0   56.465011
2013-01-03       500205           0.000000          9                           Ahipara  Far North District  Far North District            9.0    0.000000
```